# A question was closed as duplicate, but I dissagree with it (I am not OP). What is the correct way of bringing this up?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Today, User Andy aka closed [a question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/359830/beta-for-inverting-amplifier-via-op-amp) as duplicate. I however disagree with this, as in my opinion this question was regarding something far more specific than the general solution provided in the question it was supposed to be a duplicate of. However, I don't want to start a "yes it is - no it's not - yes it is - etc" in the comments.

Is there a standard practice to bring this up? I don't want to "undermine" Andy aka, nor do I want to go out and say that Andy aka is "wrong" and I am "right" since I don't have any authority to make that claim.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that Andy can single-handedly close a question, but maybe there's some information missing. Maybe I'll write a new meta-question about that.

Comment: @pipe because Andy has a "op-amp" gold badge. Owners of gold tag badges can single-handedly close as duplicate questions that have this tag (You'll see the tag next to Andy's name within the close annotation. Hover your mouse over, it's explained).

Comment: @pipe hmm really? In that case Andy may not even have known he was hammering it closed..

Comment: @Trevor: That's entirely likely.  I have several such gold badges, and am still surprised each time my close vote ends up closing the question regardless of the number of other votes.  It's not something I think about until it happens.  Note, however, that this gold badge close ability only applies to closing as a duplicate, not any of the other reasons.

Comment: I wasn't aware (prior to this) that I could single handedly close a question. I did notice it at the time and I thought "odd" but double checked that I felt the answer given by LvW enhanced the understanding for the OP and got rid of a question that was flawed in a very specific way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard practice would be to add a comment under the question, and then nominate the question to be reopened, which places it in the review queue to be examined by other community reviewers.